# Azure WebJobs And correct syntax for crone schedule and job trigger

Tags: c#, azure, cron, webjob

I have uploaded a settings.job file containing {"schedule":"0 0/10 0 ? * * *"} in to my job root folder

[image]

But that doesn't seems to trigger(app is set to always on). for what I understand this should run EVERY 10 minutes.

What is correct crone syntax? I have found at least 3 different examples.

> 0 0/10 0 ? * * *
>
> 0 */10 * * * *
>
> */10 * * * *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure WebJobs and Azure Functions are using the [NCronTab](https://github.com/atifaziz/NCrontab) library to parse CRON expressions. There is a guide on how to correctly define the NCronTab expression which can be found on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer#ncrontab-expressions). There's also a pretty good [cheatsheet](https://codehollow.com/2017/02/azure-functions-time-trigger-cron-cheat-sheet/) which I'm using, and it states:

> 0 */5 * * * * every 5 minutes

So just replace 5 to 10 and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

The right cron expression should be like the below format:

```
{second} {minute} {hour} {day} {month} {day-of-week}
```

Check the doc [NCRONTAB expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer#ncrontab-expressions), so your cron should be `0 */10 * * * *`.